# Does ES8's ANN provide accurate similarity scores and rankings among the k results?

Tags: elasticsearch, knn

[As per the ES8 documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#approximate-knn), when running an ANN query with k=100, Elastic will:

1. Find the 100 closest neighbors, using the HNSW approximation
2. Calculate each result's similarity and rank them using the specified similarity algorithm (eg, `dot_product`)

I understand that by design, ANN uses approximations in step 1. So the 100 results aren't guaranteed to be the 100 nearest neighbors. The `recall` metric [in the benchmarks](https://elasticsearch-benchmarks.elastic.co/#tracks/dense_vector/nightly/default/90d) reflect the percentage of the nearest neighbors that are returned by ANN, and this is unlikely to be 100%.

However, are approximations used in step 2 as well? Given a set of 100 results, are they guaranteed to have accurate rankings and similarity scores (eg, using precise `dot_product` calculations)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question on the elastic.co forums and [received an answer](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/accuracy-of-the-scores-and-rankings-in-ann-output/336009):

> The dot_product calculation is not approximate. As vectors are stored, the graph is built with the actual dot_product calculation and when the graph is explored, we calculate the actual dot_product between vectors.